# Power Bi Combining/Manipulating Column Orders

Tags: sorting, powerbi, powerquery

Looking to convert a teams rota into Power Bi, to show a heatmap of when people are in the office. I have a method but it seems too resource heavy. Explaining the method used below but I believe there is a better way.

The Data looks like the following

[image]

Step 1: Put Start and end times in their own column. Used split by delimiter ' - ' to leave the following

[image]

Step 2: Referenced the main rota table and created separate tables for each person.
Ie Person 1 table with Date, Day, Start and End. Then Person 2 etc.

Step 3: Removed null values

Step 4: Merged all individual tables together to leave values like this

[image]

Step 5: Heatmap which I already have down as process and don't need to change

I think there is a better way to do Step 1 - 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just click select the first two columns, then right click and "unpivot other columns". Does that get what you want ?  You can then filter by person and null rows will automatically disappear. Right click the column and split on the **-** character to get start/end times into separate columns